# Compare two matrices and replace elements that smaller

Tags: matlab

I want to compare two matrices and replace elements that smaller by one value. For example, I have matrix A and B, that

```
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
B=[9 2 5;6 2 1]
```

And then I want to compare elements of matric A with elements of matric B. If value of the element in matrix A smaller than vaule the element in matrix B. I will replace them by one vaule (Example 0). And assign that matrix as A. The result is

```
A=[0 2 0;0 5 6]
```

How to implement it in matlab? Thank all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A(A<B) = 0`

This is called logical indexing. `A < B` is a logical matrix.

Answer (score 3):

```
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
B=[9 2 5;6 2 1]
issmall = A<B; % find elements of A that is smaller than B, issmall is a logical array.
A(issmall)=0; % index using the logical array. And make corresponding values 0
```